# Python adding List as a row to Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I have an empty existing dataframe with columns

```
In[337]: df_short_interests.columns
Out[337]: 
Index(['Settlement Date', 'Short Interest', 'Avg Daily Share Volume',
       'Days To Cover'],
      dtype='object')
```

I have a list below which I would like to add as a row to the dataframe.

```
row_data = []
row_data.append('2/15/2019')
row_data.append('39,903,215')
row_data.append('26,937,971')
row_data.append('1.481300')
```

I tried to add the list with the below code and I got warning and the list get added as a column instead.

```
In[334]:df_short_interests.append(row_data, ignore_index=True)
C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\api.py:107: RuntimeWarning: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int', sort order is undefined for incomparable objects
  result = result.union(other)
Out[334]: 
   Settlement Date  Short Interest     ...      Days To Cover           0
0              NaN             NaN     ...                NaN   2/15/2019
1              NaN             NaN     ...                NaN  39,903,215
2              NaN             NaN     ...                NaN  26,937,971
3              NaN             NaN     ...                NaN    1.481300
```

How can I add the list a row instead of a column?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Append is for adding another dataframe rows to a dataframe. So if you first would create a new dataframe, it would work:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([row_data], columns=['Settlement Date', 
                                           'Short Interest', 
                                           'Avg Daily Share Volume',
                                           'Days To Cover'])

df_short_interests = df_short_interests.append(df2)
```